# Is it possible to show a reference to a null object in UML?

Tags: java, null, uml

If so what does it look like?

I'm working with java. I want to show a reference to a null object in UML.

Thanks

Comment: First, understand there is no such thing as a `null` object, only a `null` _reference_. Second, a UML diagram shows the types, the classes, not the runtime values of fields.

Comment: In UML there is no such possible way to show values or references like `null`.

Comment: Why do you want to show a null reference in UML? What are you modeling that you need a depiction for not a value?

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I'm illustrating input values for white box tests. three of the input values are objects and one is a null reference. I just wondered if there was a way to depict this.

Comment: @user3979464 Probably, but input values for white box tests are not usually done in the [Unified Modeling Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language#Design.2FUsage).

Comment: Sotirios Delimanolis , Mandar Pandit, Please revise your comments. Some of them are wrong, as Uffe pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can indeed show objects, as well as attribute values, in UML (some of the comments on the question suggest otherwise, but this is plain wrong). How depends on context; here's an example.

First, a class diagram depicting one class having an attribute whose type is another class.

[image]

Second, an object diagram showing an object of the first class with `null` as the value of the attribute.

[image]

The attribute value could also be a named object of the other class:

[image]

So in an object diagram, which is a structural type of diagram, you simply write the attribute value into the corresponding compartment. In a sequence diagram, you can show that the result of a call is assigned to an attribute by including the attribute name in the label of the call message, as in `anAttribute = methodName(parameters)`.